# How to build a short Dynamic Link with a Desktop Fallback URL on Android?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have implemented deep link in my Android App to share content. The problem is on Android I can't find a way to set a Fallback URL when the user open the short link on his desktop.
With the Firebase DynamicLink.Builder I can set iOS fallback URL because my app doesn't exist on iOS but I can't find a way to set the `dfl` parameters in my link.
Which lead the user to an error page like this :
[image]

Here how I build my short dynamic link:

```
//link example : https://app.example.com/details/ebLvAV9fi9S7Pab0qR3a
String link = domainUri + "/details/" + object.getUid();

FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
            .setDomainUriPrefix(domainUri)
            .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().setMinimumVersion(1).build())
            // Fallback Url for iOS
            .setIosParameters(new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("").setFallbackUrl(Uri.parse(RMP_WEB_BASE_URL)).build())
            .setSocialMetaTagParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                            .setTitle(title)
                            .setDescription(description)
                            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
                            .build())
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                            shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                            //Create Shareable Intent
                            //...
                        }
                    }
            });
```

I have read that I need to specify a Desktop Fallback URL like the iOS one but DynamicLink.Builder doesn't seems to include one.
I would like to redirect my user to the home page `https://example.com` when they open the link from a non-android device.

I have tried to use `setLongLink(longLink)` in the `DynamicLink.Builder` with the parameters `?dfl=https://example.com` but it doesn't seems to work and it even break my dynamic link on android.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58874375/3480829. You need to add `ofl` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a Swift solution but may be helpful to others-**
Unfortunately, there is currently no built-in method to handle this programmatically through the Firebase url editor. You must manually add an 'ofl' parameter to the link. The easiest way to do this:

```
// Grab link from Firebase builder
guard var longDynamicLink = shareLink.url else { return }
// Parse URL to string
var urlStr = longDynamicLink.absoluteString
// Append the ofl fallback (ofl param specifies a device other than ios or android)
urlStr = urlStr + "&ofl=https://www.google.com/"
// Convert back to a URL
var urlFinal = URL(string: urlStr)!

// Shorten the url & check for errors
DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL(urlFinal, options: nil, completion:{ [weak self] url,warnings,error in
        if let _ = error{
            return
        }
        if let warnings = warnings{
            for warning in warnings{
                print("Shorten URL warnings: ", warning)
            }
        }
        guard let shortUrl = url else {return}
        // prompt the user with UIActivityViewController
        self?.showShareSheet(url: shortUrl)
    })
```

The final URL can then be used to present the shareable panel with another function like:
`self.showShareSheet(url: finalUrl)` which triggers the UIActivityViewController

Credit to http://ostack.cn/?qa=168161/ for the original idea

More about ofl: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually?authuser=3#general-params